# Pick last Vendor Number (From Master table ) who sold Item number(From detail)

Tags: sql-server

We have a master table for Receipts which has

```
RCPSEQ, RCPNUMBER, PONUMBER, VENDORNUM, DATERCPT
```

AND Detail table which has:

```
RCPSEQ, PONUMBER, ITEM
```

I want to write a query to pick the Item number and the VendorNum who recently sold us that Item. Problem is grouping. with below query I am getting multiple PONUMBEr for same item and date.

```
SELECT       
    p1.PONUMBER, 
    P2.ITEMNO, 
    (P2.MxDTAR) AS DATEM
FROM            
    dbo.PORCPL P1
    join (select ITEMNO,   max(DTARRIVAL)as MxDTAR from PORCPL group by ITEMNO) as P2
        on P1.ITEMNO=p2.ITEMNO
order by 
    ITEMNO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to rank each item by it's date, being 1 the most recent one.

```
;WITH TimingRankingByItem AS
(
    SELECT
        P.*,
        TimeRanking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.ITEMNO ORDER BY P.DTARRIVAL DESC)
    FROM
        PORCPL AS P
)
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    TimingRankingByItem AS T
WHERE
    T.TimeRanking = 1
```

Or using `GROUP BY` you should join by both the item number and the date, but if you have 2 max dates with the same item you will see both.

```
;WITH MaxDateByItem AS
(
    SELECT
        P.ITEMNO
        MaxDate = MAX(P.DTARRIVAL)
    FROM
        PORCPL AS P
    GROUP BY
        P.ITEMNO
)
SELECT
    P.*
FROM
    MaxDateByItem AS M
    INNER JOIN PORCPL AS P ON
        M.MaxDate = P.DTARRIVAL AND
        M.ITEMNO = P.ITEMNO
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys.. Got an Answer:

I grouped on Item for Detail table and then picked MAX(RCPSEQ) and later, in another view, linked the RCPSEQ with master table and selected the Vendor NUmber.